# in nonlinear binary classification problems, which is the optimal dimension for make it lineary separable?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, svm

My question pertains to linear separability with hyperplanes in a support vector machine.

Is posible to determinate the optimal dimension in which i have to transform a training data set for make it lineary separable? How can i determinate the dimension of the transformed space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can determine the optimal dimension. The main issue with you question would be that any "optimal" dimension will depend on which features you will be using or how you will combine the ones you have.

SVM can deal with up to (indirectly) infinite dimensions thanks to some mathematical tricks. Again, this depends on the specific kernel function you applied (among other factors)